# Running JUnit from the command line

Tags: junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Junit testcases from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line)

How can I run JUnit from the command line in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_1) you will find a way to do that.

As stated on [JUnit FAQ](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#running_1):

> **How do I run JUnit from my command**
>    **window?**
>
> 1. Set your CLASSPATH
> 2. Invoke the runner by "java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore (test class name)"

Comment: I did this but getting some main class not found error for org.junit.runner.JUnitCore

Comment: Are you sure your classpath is correct?

Comment: yes....The path in which my junit-3.8.1.jar is /home/myname/myroot/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/ and i have added it to my class path so that when i do echo $CLASSPATH i get /home/myname/myroot/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar

Comment: @Ammu:- Make sure you are running .class file and not the .java file.\

Comment: JUnit 3.8.1 does not have `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`. Upgrade to a more recent version of JUnit; 3.8.1 is very old.