# How to run multiple Junit test suits using commandline?

Tags: junit

I have lot of Junit testsuits in a Junit project in eclipse & wants run it using commandline, i checked one of question on stackoverflow [Running JUnit from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714688/running-junit-from-command-line) which tells to run 1 testsuit using commandline but how to run them all from a project. I am using Junit3.

Comment: "*a Junit project*" <-- a *Java* project?

Comment: sorry we have crated a Java project & added Junit cases in it using eclipse TPTP plugin.

Comment: You can build an **ant** or **maven** script that does all the test and then you will just have to execute your script from the command line. Regards,

Comment: ok is there any tool which will generate script for all Junit tests in project or i need to crate it manually?