# JUnit test outside eclipse

Tags: eclipse, command-line, junit, java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JUnit test equivalent in CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346693/junit-test-equivalent-in-cli)

I have created a java project in eclipse.  I am able to right click and export the project to and executable jar file so it can be run from the command line using the JRE tools.

For this same project I also have Junit tests.  Specifically I am using JUnit version 4.  How can I run the JUnit tests from the command line like I can in eclipse (Right Click Project-->Run As-->JUnit Test)

Comment: I am also using jre 1.7.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line as well as [JUnit test equivalent in CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7346693/junit-test-equivalent-in-cli)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use some project management tool such as Maven or Ant (for small projects). This way you'd get IDE independent project with capability to build and run tests outside of the IDE of your choice.