# How to run JUnit tests for Java from the command line

Tags: junit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run Junit testcases from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line)

I've run my JUnit tests using maven before. Now I'm packaging all my source code into a JAR file, and want to run it using a `java` command. How can I do that? Note that there is no main class in my code.

Answer (score 17):

You need to make sure the classpath contains

1. Your JAR
2. The JUnit JAR

You can set the class path by using the `-cp` flag to the `java` command. Then you can use [`junit.textui.TestRunner`](http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/textui/TestRunner.html) to run the tests.

If you're using Linux (note the use of `:` as the path separator between jars)

```
java -cp /path/to/my.jar:/path/to/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.mypackage.MyClassWithUnitTests
```

If you're using Windows (note the use of `;` as the path separator between jars)

```
java -cp /path/to/my.jar;/path/to/junit.jar junit.textui.TestRunner com.mypackage.MyClassWithUnitTests
```

Comment: its not junit.textui.TextRunner, but junit.textui.TestRunner

Comment: For Junit4 you can use this:
java -cp /path/to/my.jar;/path/to/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.mypackage.MyClassWithUnitTests