# How to add arguments to junit test triggered from command line?

Tags: java, junit4

This thread here shows how to test a JAR with JUnit tests. However, I want to submit additional properties from the command line (because I want to test my main method).

[How to run JUnit tests for Java from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902983/how-to-run-junit-tests-for-java-from-the-command-line)

e.g.
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [MyTest] [PortNumber] [fileToRead]

Anything like that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use system properties

```
java -cp ... YOUR_TEST -DportNumber=1234
```

Then in code, you can retrieve it with

```
System.getProperty("portNumber")
```