# Running Android Junit tests from command line

Tags: java, android, bash, command-line, junit

I want to be able to run Junit tests from the command line, but when I run this command

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

All I get back is

```
OK (0 tests)
```

Does it have something to do with it being an Android project?  I've run that command before and haven't had much issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just managed to run JUnit tests from command line, but using an adb shell.

The command was

```
./adb shell am instrument -w com.dddforandroid.api/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

More details [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_otheride.html#RunTestsDevice).

Comment: This has ended up being my final solution.  I just don't understand why the Junit runner wouldn't be able to pick it up.  But whatever works I guess.

Comment: I suppose `com.dddforandroid.api` is your custom package here, with the tests?

Comment: But isnt that an instrumented test then? I mean the whole idea about unit tests is to not build a whole app, install it on a device and run it there. I understood intrumented tests do exactly this (opposite to unit tests). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```
adb shell am instrument -w <YOUR_PACKGE_NAME>.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Example:

```
adb shell am instrument -w com.example.android.testing.blueprint.flavor2.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

Details on Google's github page: [Android Testing Blueprint](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing-templates/blob/master/AndroidTestingBlueprint/README.md)