# How to uninstall and reinstall application while running each test cases

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit4, uninstallation

I am using `junit` to test my android application. In `TestCase1.java` I am clicking on 'Agree' button to accept the agreement and then assert some possibilities.

In next `TestCase2.java` again I want to click on 'Agree' button and assert some possibilities.

Each time when I run test cases I have to uninstall the application and have to reinstall it. If I run the whole package most of the cases fails because I am repeating the same path.

Sample codes.

**TestCase1.java**

```
  @Test
  public void testdA_Case2() throws Exception {
  solo.assertCurrentActivity("my test  active", Myproj.class);
    solo.clickOnButton("I Agree");
    assertEquals(Getresponce(),"1");
}
```

**TestCase2.java**

```
 @Test
  public void testdA_Case2() throws Exception {
  solo.assertCurrentActivity("my test  active", Myproj.class);  
  solo.clickOnButton("I Agree");
    assertEquals(register(), true);`
```

How can I run the test so that application should reinstall before each testcase. How to automate it. (I tried clear the application data and I tried uninstall by using Uri

```
packageURI = Uri.parse("package:"+"myproj.com");
        Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        ctx.startActivity(uninstallIntent);
    `  But my test stops running if I tried this.
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can't reinstall your apk from within a test case as they are all run within the application.

But you can implement the desired flow control from outside.

From a batch/shell script, you can call adb install -r .... as needed and run separate test projects . here's how to run one: [Running Android Junit tests from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144466/running-android-junit-tests-from-command-line)