# class import not resolved on external jars installed in maven local repository

Tags: java, maven

I am using maven 3.2.5. I have one external jars which I need to use in my maven project which is not available in maven repository.

I installed those jars by using following command:

1) `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=p-unit-0.15.319.jar -DgroupId=org.punit -DartifactId=p-unit -Dversion=0.15.319 -Dpackaging=jar`

2) After this command, I saw in my M2 repository, jar & pom was created
.m2\repository\org\punit\p-unit\0.15.319\p-unit-0.15.319.jar
.m2\repository\org\punit\p-unit\0.15.319\p-unit-0.15.319.pom

created pom content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.punit</groupId>
  <artifactId>p-unit</artifactId>
  <version>0.15.319</version>
  <description>POM was created from install:install-file</description>
</project>
```

3) Updated the pom file

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.punit</groupId>
  <artifactId>p-unit</artifactId>
  <version>0.15.319</version>   
  <scope>provided</scope>                                         
</dependency>
```

Issue:  When I tried to use class of this jar,

```
 import org.punit.runner.*;
 getting error: import org.punit.runner can't be resolved.
```

I tried many combination to define the dependency but not able to use the classes.

How can I resolve it??

Comment: what jar do you need to use?

Comment: please share your entire pom.xml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105556/the-import-org-junit-cannot-be-resolved something similar should help

Comment: You should most probably remove `<scope>provided</scope>`. But your question isn't clear: what do you mean by *When I tried to use class of this jar*?

Comment: After removing the "scope" also it's not able to resolve. When I tried to use class of this jar? I mean, I am trying to import runner package which is in p-unit-0.15.319.jar(which I installed in my local repo).

Comment: Thanks nullpointer,  .. your link has solved my issue..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing which I missed, I am mentioning here, which solved this issue.
I had put the dependency in wrong profile which was not called during my compilation.
When I put in correct profile it worked.

> Second option:

**We can directly add external jar through eclipse:**

> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars.
>
> and locate the library on the file system.

Answer to similar query: 
[The import org.junit cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105556/the-import-org-junit-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Add the corresponding dependency to the `pom.xml` file of your project under the tag dependencies.

Example :

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.punit</groupId>
      <artifactId>p-unit</artifactId>
      <version>0.15.319</version>   
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

***Note*** : assuming the group,artifact ids and version are correct as mentioned in the question.

Comment: I have added corresponding dependency in my pom also. but still its not able to resolve the class.

Comment: Yes its correct only... I have pasted my install command and the dependency part also... Is there any other thing which may cause this issue?