# Importing junit.Test & junit.Assert.* into NetBeans java project

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, netbeans-8.2

I am using NetBeans 8.2, which comes with JUnit 4 as a plugin, but I cannot get it to import properly so that I can use the assertTrue(); method, among others. Here is what I am trying currently based on what I have researched online:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
```

But to no avail...I've tried variations like adding JUnit 5 to my Test Library and using the jupiter.api import, but nothing is working.

The error I am getting is: package org.junit does not exist

Any tips are much appreciated.

Comment: what dependency management system are you using? maven? gradle?

Comment: I don't believe I am using one at all.

Comment: yeah you gotta add junit to you classpath using some sort of dependency management or manually inserting the jar (please dont do that learn the proper way)

duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15105590/4682816

Comment: Great thanks, I will check it out and update the post.