# org.junit.test is not accessible in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this problem in eclipse:

[eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c649Z.png)

I don't know why it kee[s telling me that its not accessible.

I tried to find a solution onlines and tried a couple but couldn't work it.

Comment: Have you tried adding `junit` library to your Eclipse project? [The import org.junit cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105556/the-import-org-junit-cannot-be-resolved/36763917)

Comment: Please take the [tour] and have a read through [ask]. And please do not post screenshots of text, but do post the text itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line 2

```
import static org.juni
```

Is 1) incorrect, and 2) not terminated with a `;` (semicolon). So the compiler assumes your line 4 is a continuation of this *broken* one, which is still an error.

In all likelihood, you want your line 2 to be:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a bug in eclipse (using version 2022-06 (4.24.0), build id: 20220609-1112) that causes such problems. You will get such error messages if you chose to create a Java project *with* the `module-info.java` file. You may add the "missing" methods to this file, but you will get runtime errors, as they are still missing.

The moment you delete this file, the JUnit errors vanish!

Comment: Thanks. I have that exact Eclipse version and this solved my problem.

Comment: Not true. This is not an Eclipse bug but how [`module-info.java`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules) works. And according to the screenshot, there is not even a `module-info.java` file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and struggled to find the core of it, here is the things that you need to do:

1. Right click your project name --> properties --> java build path --> libraries --> Class path --> then add Junit 4 library,
   Module path --> then add your external JARS
   --> apply and close.
   you can do it when creating your project or after creating it.
2. Make sure that **module-info.java** has the line (requires junit;)

that's it.