# Run JUnit tests automatically in Jenkins without maven or ant

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am currently setting up a continuous integration tool with Jenkins. I would like to run JUnit tests everytime a build is made. My problem is that none of the projects that will be tested use maven or ant. So I would like to know if it is possible to run these tests without maven or ant, and if it is, how do I do it ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: How are you planning to build the project without Maven or Ant?

Comment: You can build without these tools. It's harder, and longer, but possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [ClasspathSuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) by Johannes Link?

From the documentation:

> The mechanism is simple. Just create a new project in Eclipse and add
>   all projects that contain tests you want to run to its build path. Now
>   create a class like that:
>
> ```
> import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
> import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
> @RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
> public class MySuite {}
> ```
>
> This will execute all JUnit4 testclasses (those containing methods
>   with the @Test annotation) in the projects classpath.

You can then run it using [JUnitCore](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java).

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
```

For more information, see [How to run Junit testcases from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-testcases-from-command-line).

Comment: I didn't konw about this. But that's exactly what I needed ! Thanks !