# Integration testing using Jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, jenkins

I am a new java developer trying to learn Jenkins for integration testing. My project is a simple Spring MVC application. I am using eclipse for building the project. I am Not using Ant/Maven etc.

I watched few youtube videos to understand integration testing using Jenkins but it is still not clear to me. So far, I can configure Jenkins to get the source code from GitHub. In Build step,  Jenkins is asking for Shell script / Ant / Maven targets. I cant understand this part.

Do I must need Ant or Maven to build Java based projects in Jenkins?

Please explain the procedure step by step. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run JUnit tests automatically in Jenkins without maven or ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669507/run-junit-tests-automatically-in-jenkins-without-maven-or-ant)

Comment: Its not a duplicate question. The link above is trying to solve the problem of Junit test cases using jenkins. I am having some jenkins configuration problem. Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you trying to run JUnit tests in Jenkins without having Ant or Maven in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins is a Continuous Integration tool. It allows Java project to automate build and deployment process. By using Jenkins you can create hourly or daily builds automatically, you can also automatically run your unit tests.

For being able to build the project, Jenkins has to use a building tool - Ant, Maven or a shell script. If you don't want to use Ant or Maven, you must configure some shell script (basic one, just to build the project) to be run at build step to enable Jenkins to build the project and run the tests.