# How to run selenium webdriver tests throught cli

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am not sure if this question is been asked before, but i couldn't find it. I want to integrate selenium webdriver tests with our existing framework which is capable of executing  commands in cli. I need to run my existing selenium junit tests in cli. Could some one point me how i can go about it? I know this can be put in a jar file . 
How do I specify a particular test if I pack it in a jar file through cli?

Answer (score 2):

This is as simple as taking your tests that happen to be selenium tests and running those on the command line.  This question doesn't really depend on selenium.  You're really just asking, "How do I run my testing tool from the command line?"  Here's how you do that with Junit: [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2235276/61624)

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/-qFv-ALK8SE