# Run java class from command line, including libraries from a jar

Tags: java, unit-testing, command-line, junit

I have a file 'Junit.class' and I run it from command line like normal (java Junit). In eclipse I run it and the imported statements work, getting them from the .jar files I have. when I run it from the command line it wont run. Eclipse made the Junit.class file and I do

```
:~java Junit
```

Errors come from it not being able to find the imported classes.Do I need to include the jar file and if so how, for example is there a way to do ?

```
:~ java (jar_File_1) (Jar_file_2) Junit.class
```

Basically I just need the jar files for the imported classes in my Junit class.

Comment: When you mean running the Junit class, you mean running the tests and not a `main` method, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 5):

You need to set the classpath to reference the relevant .jar files and directories e.g.

```
$ java -cp jarfile1.jar;jarfile2.jar;/home/user/classes mypackage.MyClass
```

Note the `;` separator is for Windows, and you should use `:` for Unix. Note also that you specify the classname *without* the `.class` suffix.

Check out the [official Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) for more info on this often confusing subject.