# How to run JUnit test from command prompt, without a main function

Tags: java, junit, jenkins, command, prompt

I want to run a simple JUnit test with Jenkins, and first I want to try it in command prompt, if it works.

The JUnit.jar file is in C:\junit.jar

I have a dynamic web project, in which I have a "test" package in which I have a LoginTest class

```
    package test;
    import junit.framework.TestCase;
    public class LoginTest extends TestCase { 
        @Test
        public void testLogin() {
            ....
            assertstuff...
        }
    }
```

I have a separate project with a TestSuite class :

```
    package test;
    import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    @RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
    public class TestSuite {

    }
```

Then I added my LoginTest class to the TestSuite build path.

If I run the TestSuite with JUnit within Eclipse it works, but I want to run it from cmd.

I tried the following in cmd :

```
    java -cp C:\junit.jar;D:\Documents\eclipse\blablabla\project_path\bin test.TestSuite
```

but it's not working.
Could you help me with this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Comment: well, i didn't learn anything from that, that's why i made this topic

Comment: Then try [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_executing_tests.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Read your command line carefully:

```
java -cp C:\junit.jar;... test.TestSuite
#        (classpath)      (main class)
```

You're telling Java to run your TestSuite's main method, which doesn't exist. Now compare the one from [the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172646/1426891) that [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3636601/jens) linked:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore [test class name]
#        (classpath)               (main class - in JUnit!)   (first argument)
```

Rather than trying to run `TestSuite`, the second command asks `java` to run `JUnitCore`, which [has a main method `java` can call](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.java#L35). After that class name, pass your test suite as the first parameter, which tells JUnitCore to load and run that class in particular.

Try this:

```
java -cp C:\junit.jar;D:\Documents\eclipse\blablabla\project_path\bin org.junit.runner.JUnitCore test.TestSuite
#        (your full classpath)                                        (main class)               (your test class)
```

Comment: This is what I get : 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: As posted on the [JUnit Download and Install Guide](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install), you need both junit.jar and hamcrest-core.jar on your classpath. Otherwise, Hamcrest classes (like org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing) will not be found (NoClassDefFoundError).