# Running JUnit tests in terminal

Tags: java, junit, terminal

I'm new to running java from the terminal and am currently trying to run a JUnit test class in terminal. The basic structure of my java classes is

```
JavaProject
    Queue.java
    QueueTests.java
    junit.jar
    RunTests
```

RunTests is a script with the following code.

```
 #!/bin/sh
 javac Queue.java
 CLASSPATH=".:junit.jar:"; export CLASSPATH
 javac QueueTests.java
 java org.junit.runner.JUnitCore QueueTests
```

However, when I run this, I always get a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" error from the final line. If i comment out the final line, there are no errors. As such, it seems like it is unable to find QueueTests.class. However, looking at the folder, it is clear after I run the script that both Queue.class and QueueTests.class are there. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2235276/1161025.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Comment: In case it doesn't answer your question, please post the full error you get.

Answer (score 0):

In the `JavaProject` folder, execute the following command:

```
java -cp .:./junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore QueueTests
```

To adapt your script, that would be

```
#!/bin/sh
javac Queue.java QueueTests.java
CLASSPATH=".:junit.jar:"
java -cp $CLASSPATH org.junit.runner.JUnitCore QueueTests
```

See also the following question: [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Comment: When I do this I get the exact same problem. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to learn and experiment new things like this in java without having to load up a full/heavy IDE and meanwhile without having to run lengthy terminal commands I would recommend you to use a lightweight java IDE like [Dr Java](http://www.drjava.org/).

PS: I am assuming that you are running from terminal just to avoid the hassle of IDE to execute and run smaller tasks like this faster.

[image]