# How to run a JUnit test from the terminal

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, terminal

I have a folder with the following subfolders and files

```
proj
    src
        Class.java
    test
        Test.java
```

The file `Test.java` issues an `import org.junit.*` command, and uses the class in `Class.java`.

I've compiled `Class.java`.  I'm now trying to compile `Test.java`.  While in the `proj/test` folder, I tried the following and several variations on it:

```
javac -cp ../src org.junit Test.java
```

and I get several errors, all related to the fact that it's not finding `org.junit` and `Class.java`.  For instance

```
error: package org.junit does not exist
```

and in reference to a class in `Class.java`:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

The nearest that I've found to my question are [about running a test from the command line, but this seems to have already successfully compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288107/run-single-test-from-a-junit-class-using-command-line) and [this one but it has a .jar file, which I don't have and I suspect I shouldn't be making one just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416697/running-junit-tests-in-terminal).  Also because I'm not using `.jar` files, [this question does not apply to my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line

Comment: @shakeel That doesn't answer my question, as I'm not using .jar files.  The commands in the answer don't work when I execute them, as I indicated in the question.

Comment: It does answer your question clearly.
java -cp /absolute/path/for/compiled/classes:/absolute/path/to/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore your.package.TestClassName
"I get several errors" -> yes you need to include those jar files in classpath to get rid of errors.

Comment: @shakeel And yet it still doesn't work, so apparently that solution isn't a solution for me.  It uses `java` whereas my scripts have not even compiled yet.  If I change it to `javac` it still doesn't compile, even after adding the jar files to the classpath.

Comment: I suggest you add ***all*** the extra info you posted in your comments into your answer, and tidy up the last paragraph a little bit. Hopefully, that *might*  get your question reopened.

Comment: In that case i would suggest to elaborate the errors you receive when you compile(after including jar files). That's first step . Also share the command you use to compile and how you include jar files.