# Execute JUnit on comiled jar files with CLI on Linux

Tags: java, junit, command-line-interface

Is it possible to execute `JUnit` test on a jar file, I created earlier?

I tried:

```
java -cp myJarFile.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myPackage.myClass
```

and

```
java -cp myJarFile.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myPackage.myClass.myMethod
```

and

```
 java -cp myJarFile.jar:path/to/junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myJarFile.jar myPackage.myClass
```

I'm getting an error: Could not find class: `myPackage.myClass`

The method is annotated by `@Test`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line

Comment: I found it, read it, tested it, and have that error. For me it seems like they do not use their own compiled project, but the sourcefiles.

Comment: It seems `junit.jar` is missing in your classpath.

Comment: also fails with the same error.

Comment: Can you post the concrete command? What is the content of your jar file?

Comment: The jar contains a main(String[] args) array and several packages, classes. Beside, there is a testclass, which has some methods annotated with `@Test`. I can perfectly use `eclipse` to `run as JUnit test`. This is the concrete command. I just shortened the paths.

Comment: Just looked at your posted commands more closely. The first two, are missing `junit.jar` in classpath. The third has `myJarFile.jar` a second time after `JUnitCore`.  You need `java -cp myjar.jar:junit.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore myPackage.myClass` (without `.class` in myClass)

Comment: how do i now, which classes are inside the 'jar', if i just have the 'jar' file?

Comment: `jar tf <jarfile>` list all files contained (look into the manual for details)