# how to use junit from the terminal

Tags: java, junit, terminal

I am trying to use junit in the terminal.
I have a class Abc.java

```
class Abc{
    public int add(int a, int b){
         return a+b
    }
}
```

and i have created a class AbcTest.java

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

class AbcTest {
    public void testAdd() {
        System.out.println("add");
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        Abc instance = new Abc();
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = instance.add(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
}
```

when i am running the command

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar AbcTest.java
```

I am getting the following error output

```
AbcTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
Abc instance = new Abc();
^
symbol:   class Abc
location: class AbcTest
AbcTest.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
Abc instance = new Abc();
                   ^
symbol:   class Abc
location: class AbcTest
2 errors
```

I tried to build the project with the command

```
javac -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar *.java
```

it build up properly, but running this command

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore AbcTest
```

throws the following error

```
JUnit version 4.11
Could not find class: AbcTest
Time: 0.002
OK (0 tests)
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line There are so many suggestions and discussions about running from terminal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add current directory (or the directory where the compile class file are) along with the necessary jar files to class path.

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/junit4.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore AbcTest
```

FYI When I tried to run the same test case I used (jar files and class files in current directory)

```
javac -cp junit-4.11.jar:. AbcTest.java
java -cp junit-4.11.jar:hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore AbcTest
```

And had to modify the AbcTest.java as

```
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;


public class AbcTest {
    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        System.out.println("add");
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        Abc instance = new Abc();
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = instance.add(a, b);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
    }
}
```

Changes:

1. public class AbcTest
2. @Test annotation for testAdd method

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was missing out on adding the current directory while running.

Comment: however the problem gets back when I move the Abc.java to src/Abc.java and AbcTest.java to test/AbcTest.java.

Comment: You need to add the directory with the compiled class files to classpath using -cp option. In the above example I used '.' It denotes current directory.

Answer (score 0):

JUnit's own [Get Started page](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started) is a detailed How-To for running JUnit from the command-line.