# junit4.jar and test file in same folder, can't find class

Tags: java, junit4

I have **junit4.jar** in a folder along with **TestMain.java**

I successfully compiled test main, then I attempt to run it from command line with

```
java -cp junit4.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestMain
```

I get this error message

```
JUnit version 4.10
Could not find class: TestMain
```

But they're in the same folder! What am I missing here?

Comment: it might belong into the `libs` directory and the class into the `test` directory.

Comment: I don't have a project with directories. I have TestMain and junit.jar in one folder together. I need to run junit on TestMain which in turn runs a class loader and loads some other classes in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the current directory to the classpath.

Try (I added **:.** after **junit-4.10.jar**)

`java -cp junit-4.10.jar:. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestMain`

Please note that the JUnit version in your error message is different from the `-cp` jar version. I used version 4.10 because this is the one your error message shows.

Source: [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31504242/9791840)

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I get new error, `Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` In my question, I was loading junit just fine. The test runner just can't find the TestMain class also in the same folder.

Comment: @ThisClark what operating system do you use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528438/classpath-does-not-work-under-linux

Comment: Windows Linux or OSX

Comment: @ThisClark your original error message says your JUnit version is 4.10. Therefore your jar should be junit-4.10.jar. I updated the answer.

Comment: I renamed the jar. That’s irrelevant, but for what it's worth I put the name back to junit-4.10.jar and still no difference. In fact the `:.` at the end makes it completely not work. The problem is finding TestMain not running Junit. To be clear, JUnit is working okay, but it just doesn't see the class in the same folder with that name, TestMain.