# AWS-Device farm Uses TestNG Framework Regardless of selecting Appium Java Junit for Testing

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, appium, aws-device-farm

I'm working with AWS-Device Farm and I followed the steps specified to run my test package, I have selected Test Configuration Appium Java Junit But All of my test cases failed. So After looking at popup messages displayed along with error messages I notice that AWS Runs My test cases by converting my junit test cases to TestNG. How to overcome this issue please suggest some solution.

Comment: Hey, it seems amazon convert all junit tests to be as TestNG, but this should not be a problem for you, i did run a junit that uses jbehave on the device farm, and executed correctly, it seems you have another issue, if you can specify more about the issue it self, like does your code getting executed at all or not, and if your test executed what exactly is the error it shown

Comment: Device Farm will run all the junit tests using a testng runner
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_run_junit_tests.htm

so it may be the case that the issue is related to one of the issues in the testNG github. 

https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+junit

I agree with Khalid, we need more information to figure out what went wrong. Can you send us a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

In Device Farm's [custom environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html), it's possible now to change the command to start the test. A java JUnit command can be used the [testspec file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/custom-test-environments.html#custom-test-environment-example) in theory to run the java tests using JUnit instead of TestNG.

I found [these commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172646/112233)(not tested) which could replace the TestNG command.