# Unable to run project in Netbeans, no classes are created

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm trying to run a project in Netbeans, but I'm running into some major problems. When I build project (F11) it creates a jar file instead of simply creating classes, and I'm unable to run the project because no classes were found. I suspect it might be because I added a jar file as a library.

Anyway, when I build the program it tells me to run it from command line by using `java -jar program.jar`. So I try that and I get `Error: Could not find or load main class something.java`. In project properties correct class is chosen to be a main class.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need your project settings to use (ex: main.java) as the main file. You should find a setting like that in the project settings.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

Error: Could not find or load main class something.java

Is looking specifically for a method `public static void main(String args[])`

Does that exist in any of your classes?

Netbeans will automatically compile class files on the fly when saving a source file.

ed:

To run a JUnit test, see this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7172646/288915

Comment: Hmm it doesn't, but the problem is that I didn't create that class and it is supposed to be used to test if my program works correctly (using assert)

Comment: To "run" a program, the program has to have a starting point. That is always `public static void main(String args[])`. Without that, there is not starting point, and therefore the program will fail to do anything.

Comment: @mandatory . If you're using "assert" are you using a testing library, like JUnit? There needs to be a "beginning" for the JVM to start at.

Comment: Yes I am using junit. Could that explain why there is no main?

Comment: @mandatory You need to call JUnit differently than a regular "jar" execution. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7172646/288915