# Why won't jUnit 4 find my expected Exception?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I managed it to understand Junit 3.8 but honestly I have no idea how junit 4 works even after I read documentations for more than 45 minutes. I don't have a problem with the annotations but with **running the tests**.
For example junit won't find my expected exception in this little example:

Output:

```
.E
Time: 0,011
There was 1 error:
1)     testTest(junittests.TestTestCase)java.util.InputMismatchException
```

Main.java

```
TestRunner.run(TestTestCase.class);
```

DemoClass.java

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class DemoClass {
    public void test() {
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    }
}
```

TestTestCase.java

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Before;

import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class TestTestCase extends TestCase {
    private DemoClass inst;
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        inst = new DemoClass();
    }
    @org.junit.Test(expected = InputMismatchException.class)
    public void testTest() {
        inst.test();
    }
}
```

I really have no clue how to use it. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Don't extend TestCase. Don't use any class from the junit.framework package. They're there to be able to run legacy JUnit 3 tests. They shouldn't be used in JUnit 4.

Comment: Can confirm, was able to recreate the problem. Removing the ```extends TestCase``` solved it.

Comment: hi guys! When I remove the `extends Test Case` the line `TestRunner.run(TestTestCase.class);` produces a error. "No suitable method found for run". I guess I need another Runner-Class but which one?

Comment: tbh I always use the eclipse JUnit launcher. But [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line) suggested using ```org.junit.runner.JUnitCore```. I tried ```JUnitCore.runClasses(DemoClassTest.class);```, It returns a ```Result``` object which you can query for information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does this mean in junit 4 I'm not longer using textui/awtui/swingui?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

Your test class.

```
public class DemoClass {
    public void test() {
        throw new InputMismatchException();
    }
}
```

Test class in the same package:

```
public class DemoClassTest {
    @Test(expected = InputMismatchException.class)
    public void testTest() {
        new DemoClass().test();
    }
}
```

I can run this all day in IntelliJ.