# Use Junit or TestNG with the windows shell

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, unit-testing, junit

I want to launch my JUnit test using the command line on windows.
I have already seen thread about it in this page : 
[How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

This is the command line i use to launch it :

```
java -cp C:\Junit\junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    'C:\Users\FORNAME NAME\workspace\Project\test\TheClassIWantToTest.class'
```

And i have the following error :

> Could not find class : TheClassIWantToTest Exception etc

I'm sure that I did not make an error writing the way to the file because I used auto completion. And the class is found when I launch it without `JUnit`.
I have tried with and without the .class at the end of the filename.

I have the exact same error when i try to launch a `TestNG` by command line.

Anyone already had this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This time I've followed [Junit Getting Started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started) link, and the example works.

Below are the steps that I did in Windows;

1 : I created the folder **test** on my Desktop

2 : Inside **test** , I create the Calculator(Calculator.java) file

```
public class Calculator {
  public int evaluate(String expression) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String summand: expression.split("\\+"))
      sum += Integer.valueOf(summand);
    return sum;
  }
}
```

3. Inside **test** , I created the CalculatorTest(CalculatorTest.java) file

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class CalculatorTest {
  @Test
  public void evaluatesExpression() {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    int sum = calculator.evaluate("1+2+3");
    assertEquals(6, sum);
  }
}
```

4: I downloaded Junit 12 jar from [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12)(Note : this example do not use maven, I use only maven repository to get the jar file).

5: I downloaded hamcrest-core 1.3 jar from [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3) (Note : this example do not use maven, I use only maven repository to get the jar file)

6: The **test** folder looks like this
[image]

7: I opend the CMD and go to root of **test** folder and execute this command

```
javac -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar *.java
```

Note: ***.java** compiles all the files with java extension, in this case CalculatorTest.java and Calculator.java

8: The test folder looks like now like this
[image]

9: I executed the command

```
java -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
```

Note: this sentence must to add the dot(.) in the classpath, otherwise Calculator file is not find it and you will get

```
initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class
```

And finally I get  the unit test running by command line how  you can see below

[image]

At this point the example does not inlcude the **package** keyword, which has to add the physical folders on Windows to running the test, lets explain this case

1: Let's add the package "stackoverflow.junit.test" to files Calculator.java and CalculatorTest.java

```
package stackoverflow.junit.test;

public class Calculator {
  public int evaluate(String expression) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (String summand: expression.split("\\+"))
      sum += Integer.valueOf(summand);
    return sum;
  }
}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.junit.test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

    public class CalculatorTest {
      @Test
      public void evaluatesExpression() {
        Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
        int sum = calculator.evaluate("1+2+3");
        assertEquals(6, sum);
      }
    }
```

2) now it is posible to compile the code with the same instruction show before `javac -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar *.java` . However if I want to run the test I will get java.lang.NotClassDefFoundError

[image]

To solve this problem the folders had to been created physically and added the Calculator.java and CalculatorTest.java

[image]

3. With my right structure of folder I compiled and run the test, but having in account that this command are executed from **test** folder root on. What is more, the name of the package has to be add.

   javac -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar stackoverflow/junit/test/*.java

   java -cp junit-4.12.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;. org.junit.runner.JUnitCore stackoverflow.junit.test.CalculatorTest

[image]

**Recommendation:** All this will be less tedious if you use Maven or Gradle.

**Recommendation:** Check the structure of your proyect as well your CLASSPATH.

Comment: This message really helped me, it seems that it was the hacrest-core that was needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
java -cp .;C:\Junit\junit-4.11.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
    'C:\Users\FORNAME NAME\workspace\Project\test\TheClassIWantToTest.java'
```

Or try to create a **Test Runner Class**.

See this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_executing_tests.htm) for an example on how to do that.

Comment: For anyone wondering what's different between the two java commands: one has `-cp .;C:\bla`, the other one just `-cp C:\bla` (missing the current working directory, indicated by the `.`)

Comment: @stuXnet  the dot (`.`) represents the existing classpath, or as well call it the current dicrectory. What it means, if you are in the path `C:\Users\user\workspace`  and execute the command with dot(.) the java or javac command will looking for resources(whatever it was, a `.class` , `.jar` or `.java`) in that path.

Comment: I have the same result, i will try the Test Runner class, but can someone tell me why it's not working ?

Comment: @CarlosAndrésGarcía I know, but thanks for adding that but of information for others :)
I was just comparing your snippet with that from the OP, and thought "Huh, aren't they the same?", until I noticed the dot :)