# Which command should i use to execute particular class without main in cmd while runnable jar file is created for whole project

Tags: java, junit, jar, cmd

I have created classes under package without main method and maintain one util class with main method in different package to run.. Now I am executing all classes with the help of junit.. I have created runnable jar file for my whole project and **I want to execute a particular class without main method in cmd with the help of jar file.**

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *execute a particular class*?

Comment: 1.I have created runnable jar file for my x project in eclipse.
2.The classes which  i have created under packages are not having main method..simply call that classes as test cases
3.I have created one class with main method i..e Junit framework and  i am executing that class for all my classes..i.e

Comment: 1.I have created runnable jar file for my x project in eclipse.
2.The classes which  i have created under packages are not having main method..simply call that classes as test cases
3.I have created one class with main method i..e Junit framework and  i am executing that class for all my classes..i.e
4.I want execute the class in cmd which is not having main method..ex:java -jar xproject.jar myclassname
5.how can i execute above ex command is not working

Comment: this [SO post] {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line} has the answer