# Concourse CI junit test

Tags: junit, concourse

I am new to concourse CI. Can someone point me to the right direction? I would like to know how I can run junit using concourse CI. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

-Dd

Answer (score 0):

You should play around with concourse for a little bit to get the hang of things before building your own pipeline. The best resources for learning are the [flight school tutorial](https://concourse.ci/flight-school.html) and the [stark and wayne tutorial](https://github.com/starkandwayne/concourse-tutorial).

Hopefully these two resources will help you understand how concourse uses containerization to accomplish any automation task you want.

If you need any more help feel free to get on the concourse slack, http://slack.concourse.ci, and ask the developers and other heavy users any questions you have.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Concourse runs its task inside a container, which gives you a shell env. Depending on the container, you have specific tools at your disposal. If you are using a maven image in the task definition e.g.

```
---
platform: linux

image_resource:
  type: docker-image
  source: {repository: maven, tag: "3.4"}
```

then you can execute your unit tests with maven

```
mvn test
```

If you want to run it without maven, you can just base the task on any image with java installed. Look at this post: [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I suggest to split the task definitions (.yml files) from your scripts, that makes it easier to read. Having them together in one file is good for testing and `execute`ing tasks. Here is an example: `run:
  path: inputfolder/ci/test/test.sh`