# How to write JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit

I have an assingment that require me to test if a matrix meets a certain requirement, which I have completed, and then test it in a JUnit test, which I don't know how. I have created the folder for the JUnit test but I don't know how to write the test. So far I did the test in the main class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int matrix[][] = {{2,7,6},{9,5,1},{4,3,8}};

    System.out.println(isMagicSquare(matrix));

    // changing one element
    matrix[0][2] = 5;
    System.out.println(isMagicSquare(matrix));
}

public static boolean isMagicSquare(int[][] matrix) {
    // actual code omitted for the sake of simplicity.
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at examples of JUnit tests on the JUnit web site?

Comment: Yea I tried but I couldn't find something helpful

Comment: In general, you would create another class (e.g., `TestMagicSquare`), and use annotations to mark the methods that will invoke tests (e.g., `testValidSquare()` and `testInvalidSquare()`), write the methods appropriately, and then invoke it with the JUnit system. If you are using Eclipse or another IDE, things are somewhat simplified for running the tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you create the class that you want to test.

```
public class MagicSquare
{
    private int[][] matrix;

    public MagicSquare(int[][] matrix)
    {
        this.matrix = matrix;
    }

    public boolean isValid()
    {
        // validation logic
    }
}
```

Then you create the test class.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MagicSquareTest
{
    @Test
    public void testMagicSquare1()
    {
        int[][] matrix = { { 2, 7, 6 }, { 9, 5, 1 }, { 4, 3, 8 } };
        MagicSquare square = new MagicSquare(matrix);
        // this is a valid magic square
        assertTrue(square.isValid());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMagicSquare2()
    {
        int[][] matrix = { { 2, 7, 5 }, { 9, 5, 1 }, { 4, 3, 8 } };
        MagicSquare square = new MagicSquare(matrix);
        // this is an invalid magic square
        assertFalse(square.isValid());
    }
}
```

Finally see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line) on how to run the test cases from the command line.