# How to launch JUnit 5 (Platform) from the command line (without Maven/Gradle)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, command-line, junit5

I'd like to run a class containing JUnit 5 tests from the command line. Unfortunately, I have some outside dependencies that prevent me from using Maven, Gradle, or other build systems.

In JUnit 4, I could accomplish this like

```
java .:"lib/*" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestClass
```

Is there an equivalent for JUnit 5? I'd simply like to know if test succeeded similar to when it runs in IntelliJ.

**`TestClass.java`**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class TestClass {

    private static ArrayList<Student> students;
    private static ArrayList<Student> inAgeOrderStudents;
    private static ArrayList<Student> inNameOrderStudents;

    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp(){
        initializeStudents();
        initSortedAgeStudents();
        initSortedNameStudents();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void reloadStudents() {
        Collections.shuffle(students);
    }

   static void initializeStudents(){
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();

        students.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
        students.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
        students.add(new Student(16, "Jean"));
        students.add(new Student(14, "Lin"));
        students.add(new Student(19, "Sam"));
    }

    static void initSortedAgeStudents(){
        inAgeOrderStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        inAgeOrderStudents.add(new Student(14, "Lin"));
        inAgeOrderStudents.add(new Student(16, "Jean"));
        inAgeOrderStudents.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
        inAgeOrderStudents.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
        inAgeOrderStudents.add(new Student(19, "Sam"));
    }

    static void initSortedNameStudents(){
        inNameOrderStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
        inNameOrderStudents.add(new Student(16, "Jean"));
        inNameOrderStudents.add(new Student(14, "Lin"));
        inNameOrderStudents.add(new Student(19, "Sam"));
        inNameOrderStudents.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
        inNameOrderStudents.add(new Student(18, "Tim"));
    }



    @Test
    void testMergeSort() {
        assertNotEquals(students, inAgeOrderStudents);
        StudentSortSearch.mergesort(students,StudentSortSearch.SortSearchCriteria.AGE);
        assertEquals(14,students.get(0).getAge());
        assertEquals(19,students.get(4).getAge());
        assertEquals(students, inAgeOrderStudents);

        assertEquals(true,students.equals(inAgeOrderStudents));
    }

    @Test
    void testQuickSort() {
        StudentSortSearch.quickSort(students,StudentSortSearch.SortSearchCriteria.NAME);
        assertEquals("Jean",students.get(0).getName());
        assertEquals("Tim",students.get(4).getName());

        assertEquals(students, inNameOrderStudents);
    }

    @Test
    void testBinarySearch() {
        StudentSortSearch searcher = new StudentSortSearch();
        ArrayList<Student> searchResults = searcher.binarySearch(students, 18);
        assertEquals(2, searchResults.size());
        assertEquals(18,searchResults.get(1).getAge());
        assertEquals(18,searchResults.get(0).getAge());

        searchResults = searcher.binarySearch(students, "Lin");
        assertEquals(1, searchResults.size());
        assertEquals(14,searchResults.get(0).getAge());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 43):

Sure, use the `ConsoleLauncher`.

> The `ConsoleLauncher` is a command-line Java application that lets you
>   launch the **JUnit Platform** from the console. For example, it can be
>   used to run **JUnit Vintage** and **JUnit Jupiter** tests and print test
>   execution results to the console.
>
> An executable `*junit-platform-console-standalone-<version>.jar*` with all
>   dependencies included is published in the central Maven repository
>   under the [junit-platform-console-standalone](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/junit/platform/junit-platform-console-standalone) directory. You can run the
>   standalone ConsoleLauncher as shown below.

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-<version>.jar <Options>
```

For details about the options consult https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-console-launcher please.

Tailored to your example and using JUnit Platform version `1.3.1`, the commands could look like those:

```
$ mkdir out
$ javac -d out Student.java StudentSortSearch.java
$ javac -d out -cp out:junit-platform-console-standalone-1.3.1.jar TestClass.java
$ java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.3.1.jar --class-path out --scan-class-path
╷
├─ JUnit Jupiter ✔
│  └─ TestClass ✔
│     └─ test() ✔
└─ JUnit Vintage ✔

Test run finished after 67 ms
...
```