# How does JUnit5 identify and execute runnable methods?

Tags: java, methods, junit5

I run JUnit5 tests but receive an `initializationError` (`No runnable methods`).  However, I have the `@Test` annotation on at least one method (`failingTest`).  Why is `failingTest` not identified as a runnable method (and the corresponding test case executed)?

File `StandardTests.java` ...

```
// See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-classes-and-methods
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.fail ;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test ;
public class StandardTests
  {
  @Test
  public void failingTest()
    { fail ( "a failing test" ) ; }
  } // end StandardTests
```

And in file `TestRunner.java` ...

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ;
import org.junit.runner.Result ;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure ;
public class TestRunner
  {
  public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses ( StandardTests.class ) ;
    for ( Failure failure : result.getFailures() )
      System.out.println ( "failure: " + failure.toString() ) ;
    System.out.println ( "successful: " + result.wasSuccessful() ) ;
    } // end main
  } // end TestRunner
```

I expect that method `failingTest` of class `StandardTests` would be identified as a JUnit5 test case and executed (that is, that `failingTest` would be identified as a `runnable method` and executed as a JUnit5 test case).  However, the output when I run the `TestRunner` is:

```
C:\JUnit\Minimal>C:\Progra~1\Java\JDK-12~1.1\bin\java -cp ".;junit-platform-console-standalone-1.4.2.jar" TestRunner
failure: initializationError(StandardTests): No runnable methods
successful: false
```

How can I get this JUnit5 test case (`failingTest`) to be identified as a test case and executed?

Comment: I notice that you're using JUnit 5 for your tests. I haven't dealt with manually running tests in a while, but the imports in your `TestRunner` look like JUnit 4.

Comment: @chrylis I would assume that's the reason. It will look for methods annotated with the `@Test` annoation, but for Junit4 (different fully-qualified name), not Junit5, thus it can't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have JUnit4/5 mixture: the annotations are from JUnit5 (`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`), but the runner is JUnit4 (`org.junit.runner.JUnitCore`). The last one should be smth with **`jupiter`**.

Also see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52373592/907576

Comment: I also know that I've got the similar error when I execute test with JUnit5, while `@Test` annotations are from JUnit 4 package.

Comment: Seems the JUnit developers made major design flaw when developed the new engine with such drawbacks: i met already tens of people who faced this issue.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your help.  I changed my `import` statements within file `StandardTests.java` to the following: `import org.junit.Assert ;` and `import org.junit.Test ;` .

Comment: but in this case you are running and verifying as JUnit4 using Junit5 engine (so called _vintage_ mode). Didn't you try to figure out the proper JUnit5 runner class?