# Running Spring boot Tests from with Vim

Tags: java, spring, macos, vim, command-line

I have a Mac and iTerm2 installed, I used the command `vi *file name*.java` to open and edit the file. This file has unit tests annotated with the `@Test` keyword in Spring.

How do I run these tests from the command line instead of clicking on the Test annotation in IntelliJ?

Comment: Welcome to the Java world.  There is a good deal to learn and, specific to your question, start with the [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).  There are many options - post back here if you get stuck.

Comment: You have 2 options - with maven or without maven (Assuming the original project is using maven and not gradle)  

with maven: `mvn test -Dtest= path.to.package.<YourTestClass>`
without maven: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373469/how-to-launch-junit-5-platform-from-the-command-line-without-maven-gradle/52373592#52373592

Comment: @Tintin this runs all the tests I believe. Is there a way to run one specific test?

Answer (score 1):

If using maven:
To run all test cases, go into the project's root and run (if running from somewhere else, use the path)

```
mvn test
```

To run all tests from a single class:

```
mvn test -Dtest=<YourTestClass>
```

To run a test case from a test class:

```
mvn test -Dtest=<name-of-your-test-class>#<name-of-your-test-method> test
```

If you are not using maven (or Gradle):
see: [How to launch JUnit 5 (Platform) from the command line (without Maven/Gradle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52373469/how-to-launch-junit-5-platform-from-the-command-line-without-maven-gradle/52373592#52373592)

**EDIT**: Looks like the OP is unable to run these commands in his/her setup.  Make sure you have correct dependencies and plugins (Junit and SureFire) in your pom.  E.g. I created a demo maven project with this pom (only including the Junit and Surefire).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Here are the screenshots of working mvn test commands.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I try this, I get the error ```The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory``` even tho there are multiple Pom files in this entire component

Comment: The error is self explanatory.  As I said in my answer above - you need to run this command in your projects root (thats where the pom.xml would be).

Comment: Your method still does not work, please revise

Comment: Well it does if you have a maven project.  I suspect, you don't.

Comment: I do have a maven project, I don't see why you are being so rude about this.

Comment: @WilliamJohnson I was trying to help. I added some more information that might help you (e.g. pom dependencies).  Also I have attached the screenshot of these working commands in the answer.  If this doesn't work for you, I am not sure what else conclusion to draw other than that your project is probably not set up correctly.