# Compile and run test with JUnit in command line on a single Java class

Tags: java, junit, command-line

I have a simple problem I don't know how to solve!

I have a single Java file `User.java`:

```
import java.util.Vector;

public class User {
    private String name;
    private Vector<User> friends;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.friends = new Vector<>();
    }

    public void addFriend(User newfriend) {
        friends.add(newfriend);
    }

    public boolean isFriendsWith(User friend) {
        return friends.indexOf(friend) != -1;
    }
}
```

and I have a simple test class `UserTest.java` beside this class:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;


public class UserTest {
    @Test
    public void evaluatesExpression() {
        User user = new User("foo");
        User user2 = new User("bar");
        user.addFriend(user2);
        assertEquals(true, user.isFriendsWith(user2));
    }
}
```

I want to run this test class for the `User` class.
I'm not using IDEs like IntelliJ or Eclipse, so I want to **compile** the test from linux command line, but this command:

```
javac -cp .:"/usr/share/java/junit.jar" UserTest.java
```

gives me the following errors:

```
UserTest.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
                       ^
UserTest.java:1: error: static import only from classes and interfaces
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
^
UserTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
UserTest.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class UserTest
UserTest.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
       assertEquals(true, user.isFriendsWith(user2));
        ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(boolean,boolean)
  location: class UserTest
5 errors
```

**Note:** everything I have seen on Stackoverflow is about testing a single file in a project or building and testing with gradle and ..., but I don't know much about Java and I don't need to know much, I just need to know the simplest way to create and run a test for a single Java class.

**Note2:** I have installed junit with `apt install junit` and it installed `junit-3-8-2` version.

**Note3:** I have problems when trying to **compile** my test class, I haven't even reached the stage where I can run the tests!

Comment: Off-topic, but never use `Vector`.

Comment: @shmosel thanks, but its a part of the code given to me for a project!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Comment: @PM77-1 the answers are for running the test, but I think my problem is in building the test class!

Comment: `javac -d /absolute/path/for/compiled/classes -cp /absolute/path/to/junit-4.12.jar /absolute/path/to/TestClassName.java` as described in the answer mentioned above.

Comment: From Java perspective "*test class*" is no different than any other.  You just need to have external JARs somewhere on class path.

Comment: @Andreas I tried this and it still gives me the same errors

Comment: @PM77-1 external JARs of what?? if you mean like `junit.jar` you can see that unfortunately it does not work!

Comment: No, I cannot see it.  Where is it located?

Comment: I'm sorry I must have written the command wrong, I edited the command I used to compile the class

Comment: java -cp [file path + name of your junit-3-8-2] junit.textui.TestRunner UserTest.java

Comment: @wenzi I thinks thats for running the compiled test! my test doesn't compile

Comment: Is your Java version 9 or above?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes `java --version` shows `openjdk 10.0.2 2018-07-17` I also installed java with `apt` I thought these where the defaults.

Comment: `junit-3-8-2` is way to old. It does not use the org.junit namesapce afair. Use at least 4.x.. The root cause is, that there is no `org.junit.Assert` on your classpath, because the libs you are using are before the JUnit team did a rename. But the test you are trying to run uses the 4.x code. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit/4.12

Comment: junit.jar are you sure that is the file name?

Comment: there are two files there that appear to be about junit: `junit.jar` and `junit-3.8.2.jar` and I have tested the above script with both of them.

Comment: try removing the quotes?

Comment: @wenzi still doesn't work

Comment: javac -cp ".:/usr/share/java/junit-3.8.2.jar" UserTest.java

Comment: @Andreas explained your problem.  Did you pay attention?

Comment: @wenzi that doesn't work either

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks! I missed it, there are too much comments in here!

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, using junit4 solved my problem, I will set this as the correct answer if you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Mohammad Ganji sorry for kind of distracting you from the real solution, glad that you find the solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After quite a lot of trial and error in the comments section, the root cause was an old JUnit 3.8.2 dependency. The 3.x releases used a different namespace that was changed in 4.x to `org.junit`.

Therefore the classes where not found while compiling the test.

**To debug such issues unzipping the jar with `unzip` on Linux can be helpful.**

Comment: On windows rename the .jar to .zip and open it.. Should work without any other software installed.  We use this technique to examine wars quite a bit (which are also just zip files)