# Class Not Found Exception When Running JUnit Tests from test jar

Tags: java, maven

I am building a project in a Windows Eclipse environment and then trying to test the project jar using the test jar in a Unix environment . When I run I get what is shown below. I am using Maven with the assembly plugin to package the project with the Test Jar and I can see the class that is supposedly missing inside the jar when I run the -tf command.

java -cp MyServerTest.jar:junit.jar junit.runner.JunitCore com.MyServer.services.ZoweAuthServiceTest

Results in:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.MyServer.services.ZoweAuthService
        at com.MyServer.services.ZoweAuthServiceTest.testQueryToZowe(ZoweAuthServ                                                                                                                               iceTest.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.MyServer.services.ZoweAuthService

Comment: I would advice that you add some code into your question. It will increase the chances of getting an answer and reduce the chances of having your question flagged and removed.

Comment: I guess you are running java command in a wrong place. you should put the ZoweAuthServiceTest class in the com/MyServer/services/ZoweAuthServiceTest.java path and run the command from the base folder

Comment: Have you tried executing `mvn test` instead of manually calling the test from the command line?

Comment: I am using a special version of Unix that does not have mvn.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the main answer from this post:

[How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

Make sure to running from the current directory of your jar and adjust it accordingly to junit version.

Comment: I am running it from the current directory of the jar. I have the junit jar in that directory as well.

Comment: Could you upload your code to github so I can check?

Comment: Sorry, I can't.

Comment: the class that is not being found has a BOOT-INF in the prefix before the class is specified in jar. When I run jar -tf on the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I guess I should have mentioned I am using spring-boot. Spring places the main classes of my project under a special prefix in the jar file "BOOT-INF" which prevents the test class from finding the class it wants to test. I added the classifer exec to my pom. This creates two separate jars. One for executing and one that has the normal class references for testing.

```
`<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
</plugin>`
```