# javac unable to import classes in project

Tags: java, junit4, javac

I am trying to launch a test from the windows command line using the following way described in many tutorials:

```
javac -cp .;"c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar" test\java\ColorTest.java
```

but in the result I have compilation errors in each string:

```
public class ColorTest extends BaseTest{
                               ^
  symbol: class BaseTest
src\test\java\ColorTest.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        homePage.goToHomePage();
        ^
  symbol:   variable homePage
  location: class ColorTest
src\test\java\ColorTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        homePage.moveToElement(HomePage.letterR, X_OFFSET, Y_OFFSET);
                               ^
  symbol:   variable HomePage
  location: class ColorTest
src\test\java\ColorTest.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        homePage.moveToElement(HomePage.letterR, X_OFFSET, Y_OFFSET);
        ^
```

When I add to command all my classes (`BaseTest, HomeTest`...) or use `*.java` in command - I am did get errors on each other class (`WebDriver`, `ArrayList`, etc).

Also try to joins all libraries from my local repo:

```
javac -cp .;"c:\full\path\to\.m2\repositories\*" test\java\ColorTest.java
```

But in this case `javac` did not see even `junit` package in first string.

```
src\test\java\ColorTest.java:1: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Test;
                ^
src\test\java\ColorTest.java:2: error: package org.junit does not exist
import org.junit.Assert;
```

---

- Why `javac` not imports any classes?
- How can I correctly compile the test classes from command line via `javac` and lzunch them via `java`?

Comment: First you seem to use 2 different frameworks: junit and TestNG (`import org.testng.Assert;`). You should stick to one of them only, unless you have a very specific reason to use both together.

Comment: @Benoit, I fixed it

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi Did you? `org.testng does not exist`

Comment: As an aside, I'd consider using gradle or some other build system to simplify your life.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are compiling on Windows, you need to use a Windows compatible classpath separator:

```
javac -cp .;c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar test\java\ColorTest.java
```

or possibly

```
javac -cp .;"c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar" test\java\ColorTest.java
```

Note: semicolon not colon.

---

> My better way: javac -cp c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar test\java\ColorTest.java. In this case I not get errors in import .... strings.

But you still got errors for the classes that NOT in the Junit JAR file.   Right?

IMO, what you need to do is:

- read the Oracle manual page for the `javac` command to understand `-cp` and possibly `-d` and/or `-sourcepath`.
- read the Oracle manual page for the Classpath to understand what this all actually means.

The classpath is what allows `javac` to find the compiled versions of the other classes that your code depends on.  It is an important concept.  It is a good idea to really understand it ... rather than relying on stuff copied from dubious or non-applicable examples.

In your case, your unit test classes will depend on Junit classes AND on the *compiled* classes that your test code is trying to test.  If the directory tree containing the latter is not on the classpath, or they have not been compiled, then `javac` will complain.

Now I can't work out if are still having "cannot find symbol" compilation errors.  But if you are, and the classes that `javac` can't find really do exist, then either you haven't compiled them or they are not on the classpath ... in the right way.

---

Finally you ask:

> How can I correctly launch the tests from command line via javac?

That does not make sense.  You use `javac` to **compile** classes.  To run them you use `java`.

This Q&A explains how to run Junit tests:

- [How to run JUnit test cases from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line)

And note that you need to specify the classpath correctly with `java` as well.

Comment: My better way: `javac -cp c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar test\java\ColorTest.java`. In this case I not get errors in `import ....` strings. I am did edit my question

Comment: I won't argue.  However `-cp .;c:...` and `-cp c:...` do mean different things.  The latter won't work if your `ColorTest` class depends on other compiled classes in the directory tree rooted at the current directory (`.`)

Comment: > That does not make sense. You use javac to compile classes. To run them you use java.
-
How can I use `java` command, but not compile `.java` classes with `javac`?

Comment: I read oracle tutorial (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html), so

1) `If --class-path, -classpath, or -cp are not specified, then the user class path is the value of the CLASSPATH environment variable, if that is set, or else the current directory.` - I well set the current dirrectory in command

Comment: 2) `Use the --class-path option to specify libraries to be placed on the class path. Locations on the class path should be organized in a package hierarchy. You can also use alternate forms of the option: -classpath or -cp.` - I well set the path to package/packages (`c:\full\path\to\junit-4.12.jar` or `....\repositories\*`)

Comment: There's nothing else about `-cp` or `.:` in https:\\docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html 
. Can I read anymore else?

Comment: There won't be anything *specific* about `.:`.  The `.` is simply the standard filename for the current directory, relative to itself.  (UNIX invented it, MS-DOS borrowed it. Windows inherited it.)

Comment: Read these too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/findingclasses.html

Comment: "How can I use java command, but not compile .java classes with javac?"   I didn't invent the names of the commands!   But anyway, you miss the point. You compile XXX.java to XXX.class using `javac`.  You run a XXX.class using `java`.  The link I gave you explains specifically how to run Junit tests ... using the `java` command.