Running Junit test from controller in Spring
I'm working on a Spring Boot application where i am trying to create an HTTP endpoint that can run tests and provide the results back to the client.
The goal is to have an endpoint that, when triggered, executes the tests and returns information about which tests ran and whether they passed or failed.
What is the best approach to implement such functionality in a Spring boot?
I tried to move all test classes from src/test to src/main, but I still don't know how to run it.

Why not just use a plugin like JaCoCo that generates an HTML result of the tests execution each time they run ? Tests shouldn't be included in the application sources anyway.

Are the tests a static part of the Spring Boot application, or will they be provided per HTTP endpoint call somehow?

Anyways, this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235276/how-to-run-junit-test-cases-from-the-command-line could give you some hints - you could either start a new commandline invocation, or use the class mentioned to run the tests. Still no solution on how to process the results for the HTTP request.

I tried jacoco and it is fine with that, thanks

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

better pack all test case in separate jar and run that jar on api call and get the result and return . also which api will wait for long for all test execution , you should be running first and then just share result on api call. Keep test in test folder only
